# Request cannot be converted while using AbstractValidator as a base class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, model-binding, fluentvalidation

My project throws a convert error when I use fluentvalidation class as a request model.

I have a **BaseRequest**. It is inherited from **AbstractValidatator**

```
public abstract class BaseRequest<TModel> : AbstractValidator<TModel>
{

}
```

Another model is **CreateRuleRequest** and it is inherited from BaseRequest. And also it includes some rule for its properties.

```
public class CreateRuleRequest : BaseRequest<CreateRuleRequest>
{
    public CreateRuleRequest()
    {
       this.RuleFor(k => k.Rules).NotEmpty();
    }

    public List<RuleModel> Rules { get; set; }
}
```

And I am using an Extension to load all rules that are inherited from BaseRequest. Actually, AbstractValidator extends from IValidator so that I can catch all the classes that includes rules.

```
  public static IServiceCollection AddValidation(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
    var validators = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(s => 
         s.GetTypes())
        .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IValidator))).Where(k => 
         k.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IQuery)) || 
         k.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(ICommand)));

    foreach (var validator in validators)
    {
        services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining(validator);
    }
    return services;
}
```

Lastly, I have a controller that has a Create method. This method is using CreateRuleRequest as a parameter.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] CreateRuleRequest command) =>
```

and the application throws **The JSON value could not be converted CreateRuleRequest.** I am wondering why?  is it mandatory to create another model binder or is there any other way

Comment: Your structure looks a bit odd, `CreateRuleRequest` inherits from the `BaseRequest<TModel>` abstract class, do you have a custom serializer to make it compile through as a parameter?

Comment: Also, how do you get `fluentvalidation` to work? Where is `AddValidation` called? Please provide a minimal reproducible example so we can reproduce and locate your issue.